# Nodejs(v18) streming pipe

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, stream, pipe

I need to stream a big video from an Amazon S3 bucket. Streming works fine when the user doesn't scrumble the video, but when the user scrumbles the video from 0:20 sec to example 1:00 I get an err_stream premature close message. This error only occurs when the user scrambles the video. Why is that happening?

I try to use pipeline from nodejs and the error is the same.

await pipeline(this.awsS3.stream(awsS3Key, start, end) as PipelineSource, res, {
signal: controller.signal,
});

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.